# Google Translate - Maybe general API Logic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-api

I am attempting to translate multiple elements via Google Translate API. The challenge with this being that I have no way of tying back my returned results back to the original values.

Here is a sample of what is returned with the following query:

```
https://translate/v2?key=API-KEY&target=es&q=Hello%20world&q=HTML5%20Boilerplate%20is%20a%20professional%20front-end%20template%20for%20building%20fast,%20robust,%20and%20adaptable%20web%20apps.
```

**Returned**

```
0: 
   detectedSourceLanguage: "en"
   translatedText: "Hola Mundo"
1: 
   detectedSourceLanguage: "en"
   translatedText: "HTML 5 es una plantilla para el usuario profesional para la creación de aplicaciones web rápidas, robustas y adaptables."
```

I can solve this by doing my translations one by one, but is that optimal? Does anyone else have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it return them in the same order you're passing them in?  If so, you know what was passed in and the order, you should be able to correlate them that way.

Comment: I suppose I could do that. I'd be a little afraid for longer translation lists (500+) calls, about the order being the same.

Comment: I just looked at the docs, the results will always be ordered the same as the parameters coming in.  Sounds like that's how it was designed to be used.  https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest#Translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go with Nicholas Smith's solution above.

From the docs

> Here, 'translations' is an array of objects with 'translatedText', each of which is the translation of a query in the order the user provided.